# can't get power Bi access token

Tags: javascript, angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to get access token using JavaScript/angular but I am getting error **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** and while I am calling api for accessing the token using Postman getting response code 200.

[Postman api call for token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws3bV.png)

Error on console while calling api from angular but **response code is 200** in network tab.

[error response on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOdJP.png)

[Response code 200 in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnJjj.png)

I am not able to get the Power BI access token in angular code and there is no proper documentation for accessing the token without gui based authentication in power BI.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using C#.Net you can look at the official documentation on how to get Power BI AAD token:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token

```c#
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Redirect uri must match the redirect_uri used when requesting Authorization code.
    string redirectUri = String.Format("{0}Redirect", Properties.Settings.Default.RedirectUrl);
    string authorityUri = Properties.Settings.Default.AADAuthorityUri;

    // Get the auth code
    string code = Request.Params.GetValues(0)[0];

    // Get auth token from auth code
    TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();

    AuthenticationContext AC = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri, TC);
    ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential
        (Properties.Settings.Default.ClientID,
        Properties.Settings.Default.ClientSecret);

    AuthenticationResult AR = AC.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(redirectUri), cc);

    //Set Session "authResult" index string to the AuthenticationResult
    Session[_Default.authResultString] = AR;

    //Redirect back to Default.aspx
    Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx");
}
```

If you're using any other language, you can either use a suitable AAD library (e.g. ADAL.js for js\node.js) or just use a HTTP call to the AAD endpoint using the same properties.